# Silverlight DataGrid Selected Group

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

the Silverlight Datagrid has an underlying method to group data items by using CollectionViewGroups.

Is there a way to find out if the RowGroupHeader is selected? A event to listen to or a brute force approach using the visual tree?

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely
Marco

Comment: did you find the solultion, i have the same problem :(